# Global jQuery AJAX error handling with MVC 3 unobtrusive Javascript

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a global error handler for my ajax calls that looks like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup(
{
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
    {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

And I'm making an ajax call like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Submit", "SubmitQuery", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST" })
```

On the controller action I have a CustomAuthorizeAttribute that returns:

```
filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(403, "adsfasd");
```

when the user isn't logged in.

For some reason my global jQuery AJAX error handler isn't catching the 403 error.

Comment: I also realized that I can put a function "OnFailure" but I thought that this would catch all errors?

Comment: Is the "success" function being called (or onFailure)?  If so, what if you try a 400 error instead?

Comment: Thats the thing, I would have thought that since I have the ajaxSetup that I don't need to have OnFailure, is this not true? Is there no way to globally handle ajax errors when using unobtrusive ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out.

I needed:

```
filterContext.Result = new ContentResult
{
    ContentType = "text/plain",
    Content = "Access Denied. Invalid user name and/or password."
};

filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Status = "500 ".Replace("\r", " ").Replace("\n", " ");
```